# Check whether the Control is a Button in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

How can I check whether the Control^ is a Button^ in the following code?

```
System::Void DisableControls(Control ^parent)
{
    for each (Control^ c in parent->Controls)
    {
       if(c== /*Check for Button*/)
       {
         //Do something
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx) and [`typeid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwd9abya.aspx) for this:

```
if (c->GetType() == Button::typeid) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify whether you were using WinForms or WPF. The WinForms button, [System.Windows.Forms.Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx), doesn't have any built-in subclasses, but the WPF button, [System.Windows.Controls.Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx#inheritanceContinued), does have some subclasses, and if you're using one of those subclasses, you'll miss it if you compare to `typeid`.

Instead, I'd do a dynamic cast (equivalent to the `as` keyword in C#), and check for null.

```
Button b = dynamic_cast<Button^>(c);
if(b != nullptr) { ... }
```